# How to manage permissions for user groups for internal harddisk partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, hard-drive, users

I was advised that for managing permissions to access the partitions of hard disk you should add users to groups and I figured out how to do that.

But I don't understand how to add permissions for users in such a way that they do not have access to some specific hard disk partitions, but they have access to other partitions (without use of sudo password)

After mounting partitions as admin user, when I go to properties and then to permission, and there try to change the permissions for groups to access files/directories and I change the groups and try to save, it automatically changes to the previous setting before I can save it.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

How can I manage permissions for users to have access to hard disk partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions for managing premission by installing sofwares

I have tried mount manager and storage device manager for mangaing the partition.

Both sofware are good but **storage device manager** is easy while **mountmanager** have more functionalities.